# Get only Enterprise application via Azure powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-cloud-shell

I know I can run `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -all $true` to get a list of applications but it will return all application type including Microsoft apps and managed identities. I only want a list of Enterprise Applications only. What command I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All:$true | ? {$_.Tags -eq "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp"}
```

If you look in the portal, you will see the count of 'Enterprise Applications' if you have that filter assigned (it is assigned by default).

By running the above, if you did:

```
$noofentapps = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All:$true | ? {$_.Tags -eq "WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryIntegratedApp"}
```

and then you did `$noofentapps.count`, you would see that the numbers should match.